# Can this "new" notation for Maclaurin expansions be useful?

Tags: notation

Here is a notation for Maclaurin expansions that I made up:

\begin{align*}
sin(x) &= \sum \{alt(+); \frac{x^n}{n!}; \text{ n odd $\in$ $\mathbb{N}_0$}  \} \\
cos(x) &= \sum \{alt(+); \frac{x^n}{n!}; \text{ n even $\in$ $\mathbb{N}_0$}  \} \\
e^x &= \sum \{+; \frac{x^n}{n!}; \text{ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}_0$}  \}\\
\end{align*}

Could this notation be useful?

The $alt(+)$ is indicative of an alternating sign that starts at $+$. Similarly we could have $alt(-)$ that starts at $-$.

**Edit:**

I have come up with the following notation that might make it easier to read from left to right, that is a bit more compact, and which looks a bit more like the notation that is already in use:

\begin{align*}
sin(x) &= \sum_{\text{odd } n = 1}^{\infty}alt(+) \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
cos(x) &= \sum_{\text{even } \space n = 0}^{\infty}alt(+) \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
e^x &= \sum_{\forall \space n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
\end{align*}

Here are some properties that I thought might be useful:

\begin{align*}
alt(+)alt(+) = +\\
alt(+)alt(-) = -  \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
e^x = -alt(-)(sin(x) + cos(x))  \\
\end{align*}

This might be useful in the following way:

\begin{align*}
sin(jx) &= j.alt(+)sin(x) \\
cos(jx) &= alt(+)cos(x) \\
\\
e^{jx} &= -alt(-)(sin(jx) + cos(jx)) \\
e^{jx} &= -alt(-)(j.alt(+)sin(x) + alt(+)cos(x)) \\
e^{jx} &= -alt(-)alt(+)(jsin(x) + cos(x)) \\
e^{jx} &= -(-1)(jsin(x) + cos(x)) \\
e^{jx} &= jsin(x) + cos(x) \\
e^{jx} &= cos(x) + jsin(x) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Inventing new symbols led to the overwhelming (and in my eyes desastrous) flooding of the unicode set with gazillions of mostly useless emojis

Comment: Your alternative notation for infinite series is horrendous! The traditional notation is simple and clear. (Also, your series for $\sin$ should start at $n=0$, not $n=1$. You will no doubt claim that this error actually strengthens your case, but I'm not buying it.)

Comment: Good notation is quickly understood in a concise manner.  Having to unpack your notation for something as simple as sin(x) is already pretty difficult, and it conflicts with broadly used notation already. This post seems more of a complaint/proposal rather than an actual *question*, and I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @TonyK It does start at n=0 because I have indicated that n is odd. Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. If it looks horrendous to you, I accept that. I will proceed to use it because it is more intiutive to me.

Comment: @Hagen Invention of new symbols lead to the derivative and integral symbols as well, which are highly useful. There is always a good and bad side to everything.

Comment: @T. Bongers You can do as you please.

Comment: Honestly, it was pretty hard to read the rest of the post after "You see, calculus is quite complicated, but in its pure mathematical state its horrendous. If we had to solve calculus problems with actual mathematics, it would be utterly painful," @Gustav. I think some self-examination might lead you to a different conclusion, since this is starting to feel like "It's not immediately clear to me, so it's bad."

Comment: @T. Bongers You wanting to vote this question as off-topic instead of giving some guidance as to how to get it on topic is ironic.

Comment: @T. Bongers Actually I understand calculus really well. I have been working with it for the past 6 years. I completely understand the fundemental theorem of calculus. I am also familiar with implementing calculus in different subject areas. This is how I know that calculus can be quite difficult. I guess I could rather say that calculus can be tricky instead of difficult.

Comment: There is a **lot** of unsubstantiated opinion here. Just one immediate observation: note that using your notation to find the MacLaurin series of a sum of two functions, given their MacLaurin series, is meaningfully harder than via the usual notation (for example, note the "sign-play" in e.g. $e^x+\cos(x)$). Quite frankly I don't think this question can be made appropriate for MSE while keeping its spirit - there's too much presupposition in "What are good reasons for recycling and reusing the same symbols **past their clear conveying ability**?" *(emphasis mine)*.

Comment: My comments were primarily to point out that this comes off as a complaint or a rant, rather than a serious *question* with an attempt to understand something. This isn't a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. I don't see a quick reformulation of this question to make it on-topic

Comment: That notation is awful.  Does “alt” start off negative or positive?

Comment: @T. Bongers It does have a question. And no good question has a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: @Randall So this  notation is just a suggestion. The alt(+) starts at positive and alt(-) would start at negative.

Comment: In that case, @Gustav, you should familiarize yourself with [what an on-topic question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) might look like. If your question *doesn't* have any sort of conclusive answer, it's probably not on-topic for this particular website. A discussion forum might be a better place.

Comment: You don’t seem to think about how this notation would work for giving rigorous definitions and proofs.  Especially regarding the integral.

Comment: @Randall The integral symbol itself also does not give you any idea about how most of calculus works. This is why entire systems of notation have to be invented to fill those gaps. I was not trying to propose an entire system here, but merely a hint of what we can do.

Comment: @Gustav "no good question has a simple yes/no answer." There's an implicit false dichotomy here: the gulf between one-word-answerable-questions and open-ended-discussion-questions is actually rather large. Closely tied to this is the implicit false assumption that "good" implies "appropriate for MSE."

Comment: @Noah Certain notations are good for certain applications. The sigma notation could be more useful for your case, and my notation could be more useful to identity the underlying structure of the terms in the sum. Also certain rules can be developed to indicate how such notations would interact with each other, which is not what I was presenting here.

Comment: I mean, your $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$ should be $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Noah I have looked at your link about open-ended questions. I see what you mean. How do I remove this question?

Comment: @Gustav You should see a "delete" button just below the list of tags. Separately, it is preferred to ask a new question rather than substantially change an existing one.

Comment: @Noah I have tried this, but the site says I cannot delete it because people have invested time answering it. This is a nightmare.

Comment: @Noah I have come to my senses, but I am still being punished with my small rank being dropped.

Comment: Don't worry Gustav, 2 upvotes are worth more than 6 downvotes :-)

Comment: @Randall I have improved this question, could you consider taking it off hold?

Comment: @T.Bongers I have improved this question, could you consider taking it off hold?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have improved this question, could you consider taking it off hold?

Comment: @TonyK I hope that the new edited version will have less unpacking to do, as you have pointed out from the first rendition.

Answer (score 3):

You've asked several different questions about the history and purpose of particular mathematical notations. They have different answers.

---

For single symbols used essentially as adjectives, like $f^*$, $\hat f$ and $f'$ the meaning depends on the context, and it should. There are not enough of them to cover all the possible different uses where a short annotation is really useful.

---

In your second example you are pointing out one of the shortcomings of the $\Sigma$ notation for sums. It is indeed sometimes hard to unpack. I almost always write my sums with ellipses:
$$
\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3 \times 2} - \cdots
$$
with as many terms as I need to see the pattern.

---

Your two descriptions of integrals are not those of Leibniz and Newton respectively. The first is (essentially) Leibniz. The second is a formal definition of the integral as a limit of Riemann sums. Both are necessary and useful - the first when you are using integrals in a problem in math or physics, the second when you are actually defining integrals and proving their properties.

---

will finish later ...

Comment: I am not saying that the Riemann sum notation is not necessary. I am suggesting that in most contexts, it is better to use the Liebniz notation, which is actually representative of that. In a similar fashion I am suggesting we develop shorthand notations, or better structures, to more clearly convey ideas. This is the whole point of symbols.

Comment: Hi Ethan. Thank you for your response. I would like to delete this question to better formulate it. Could you delete your answer so that I can delete the question?

Comment: Actually, I'd rather not delete my answer so that you can delete the question. I'm not the only one who has invested time trying to answer it - and you and others can learn a lot about the nature of notation and how to ask a question by looking at this one, now closed. In principle you can edit the question in hopes of reopening - please don't, since that will make all the responses moot. Do ask more questions one at a time, respectfully, whenever you need the kind of help this site can offer.

Comment: I respect your decision. However, I do not see how anyone will benefit from the question since it has been put on hold.

Comment: @Gustav In response to your comment from two and a half years ago: someone just upvoted this answer, so probably found some benefit.